# web2py: how to download image with SQLTABLE

Tags: web2py

I'd like to know if it's possible use SQLTABLE to build up a list of images. Images are in a database table, but I don't want just a link to download.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a number of ways:

First:

```
db.table.field.represent = lambda r, v: IMG(_src=URL('default',
                                                     'download',
                                                      args=v.field))

# where field is the field where your picture lives.
```

Second is using web2py virtual fields:

```
class MyVirtual(object):
    def photo(self):
        return IMG(_src=URL('default', 'download', args=self.table.field))

db.table.virtualfields.append(MyVirtual())

table = SQLTABLE(db(db.table).select())
```

Third is using extracolumns:

```
myextracolumns = [{'label': 'My Photo',
                   'content': lambda row, rc: IMG(_src=URL('default',
                                                           'download',
                                                            args=row.field))}]

table = SQLTABLE(rows, extracolumns=myextracolumns)
```